# React does not rerender when a prop changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to develop an edit mode for a application. 
In edit mode some buttons should have a lower opacity.
A boolean variable stores if the edit mode is active. This variable is passed down to its childs using props. 
If I now change the editMode in the parents state, the childs are not being rerendered.

Parentclass:

```
export default class Parentclass extends Component{
   constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            editMode: false,
        };
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <EditButtonClass onEditPress={() => this.editButtonPress()}/>
                <View>
                    <Subclass editMode={this.state.editMode}/>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
    editButtonPress(){
        this.setState({editMode: true})
    }

}
```

Subclass:

```
export default class Subclass extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Finalsubclass editMode={this.props.editMode}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Final subclass:

```
export default class Finalsubclass extends Component{
    createStyle(){
        return{
            opacity: this.props.editMode ? 0.5 : 1,
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <TouchableOpacity style={this.createStyle()}/>
        );
    }
}
```

The button:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.onEditPress()}>
    <Image source={require('../res/edit-button.png')} style=styles.editButton}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

The editMode in props does change. If I click on one of the buttons they're getting brighter. But not directly if I enable editmode.

Whats the best way to achieve a full rerendering?

Comment: Could you please share the code for `editButtonPress`

Comment: I dont see any issue with your code, can you elaborate on what you mean by `But not all together at the time I press the button.`

Comment: I use multiple buttons which are generated in a loop. Anyway I tried the whole thing with only one button. The result is that the button color is only being updated if I click the button,

Comment: Thats because initial value is `false` which implies `opacity: 1` in your code

Comment: @Rikin Yes the initial value should be false. Once I activate the editMode it becomes true and then my button should become lighter. But that does not work instantly, only after I click the button.

Comment: That's how you have it designed `EditButtonClass`  on click toggle editMode value and thus pass down new state

Comment: Yeah thats right. And thats how it should be. But if I toggle the edit mode the button should become brighter. And that does not work

Comment: What do you mean by "if I toggle the edit mode ..."? You said that you did that by clicking a button and it worked.

Comment: There is a button for toggling the editmode. There are other buttons which should be brighter if the editmode is active. This works only in principil. But the other buttons get not updated once the editmode gets active. They only get updated when you hit them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to build a View around the TouchableOpacity and applying the styles to the view.

Answer (score 1):

you can user react lifecycle to re-render component

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

and for above issue you can use

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this way but the method is not being called.

Comment: It doesn't work because it's deprecated, use `componentDidUpdate(prevProps)` instead. If for some reason you want willReceive props use `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()`

Comment: Okay thanks, that method is being called. But how do I rerender the components to not get into a infinite rerender loop?

Answer (score 0):

As `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated, i would suggest using `componentDidUpdate`.

To answer the question in your comment, you need to check the `prevProps` with the new ones to not get an infinite loop.

For example:

```
componentDidUpdate = (prevProps) => {
    if(prevProps!==this.props){  /if the previous props are different from the current props
    //do what you need
    }
}
```

As it is an object, if you need to only check a single variable you can simply do:

```
if (prevProps.foo !== this.props.foo) {
    //do what you need
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but I was wrong. The component gets rerendered, but there is a problem with TouchableOpacity.